# AIR Mobile Live channel DVR URL not working on iPhone but it works on all android phones?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air, live-streaming, wowza

I am using open source strobe media player to build an Adobe AIR app which streams live channels. It works fine on android phones but it displays just a single frame and gets stuck in iPhone. Wowza Media Server is being used for streaming, it is integrated with Windows Server.

I am using this URL for android

```
http://202.125.131.170:1935/pitelevision/smil:dunyanews.smil/manifest.f4m?DVR
```

and this URL for iphone

```
http://202.125.131.170:1935/pitelevision/smil:dunyanews.smil/playist.m3u8?DVR
```

I am using following tools

1-- AIR SDK 4.0 OR 13.0 beta from adobe lab with Flash Builder 4.6

2-- Adobe open source Strobe player code to run live DVR.

3-- Streaming using Wowza Media Server deployed on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough info here to answer why thus isn't working.  I suggest contacting wowza's support folks and they can look at your conf and logs.  You can contact them either through the Wowza forums or the email support.

Otherwise, I would dig into your logs and see if there is some warning or error in there that might give you a clue.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you contact wowza's support, it is simply matter of days until they resolve the issue.
But if you have no time for it, you could simply install wireshark and start investigating what is different in the headers between Flash Media Server and wowza regarding iPhone. Also make sure it works fine that specific video on Flash Media Server. It could be problem with the video or most likely something specific in the headers or the encoding for the iphone.

Aleks